# Postfix - Send spam to different email address

Tags: email, postfix, spam, spam-filter, rspamd

I've researched for an answer to this question and can't find anything.

I have Postfix running on Debian Stretch. I will soon be setting up Rspamd.

Here's the logic of what I want to have happen when spam arrives:

- Postfix receives a message from the contact form on my website (via PHPMailer)
- Postfix sends the message to Rspamd for processing
- Rspamd flags the message as spam and adds appropriate headers
- Postfix does NOT send the message to me@mydomain.net, but rather spam@mydomain.net

From what I gather, it seems that milters do not have this ability. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix can check the headers set by the milter with [`milter_header_check`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#milter_header_checks). The postfix documentation also provides an example:

> The following example sends all mail that is marked as SPAM to a spam handling machine. Note that matches are case-insensitive by default.
>
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>   `milter_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/milter_header_checks`
>
> /etc/postfix/milter_header_checks:
>   `/^X-SPAM-FLAG:\s+YES/ FILTER mysmtp:sanitizer.example.com:25`

Just replace the `FILTER` action with `REDIRECT spam@mydomain.net` and it should work.
Cf. http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

Comment: Awesome Stefan! I have looked at the Postfix man pages, but have trouble understanding them. This was just the info I needed!